# Filter node by custom_field in admin panel

Tags: 7, views, panels, users

I'm using Drupal 7, Views and Panels. Created a content type and custom field (field_list) And showing contents by list on my site. Thanks Views :) But when i click find content in admin panel, many many contents in my area.

Can i add filter option by field_list in my admin panel? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install [Admin views](http://drupal.org/project/admin_views) module. It will replace administrative overview/listing pages with actual views for superior usability. Now, you can override your views for admin panel for filter content by field_list.